# Display content from local storage in a new window in safari extension

Tags: html, safari, safari-extension

I am developing a safari extension and facing some problem.

I want to display some content stored in the local storage in a new tab. I am not able to dynamically change the content of the new html page...

My question is how do i display dynamic html content in a new tab. The content is changed every time the user clicks on the extension.

Thanks in advance!!!

EDIT: one way i can think of is by using the DOM object of the javascript and retrieving the content from the local storage.. However this solution seems fallacious to me. Can anyone throw some light in this direction?

EDIT2: TO be more precise, i am developing a safari extension wherein i want to display an html file in a new tab whenever the user clicks on the extension button. 
The content i want to display in that new tab is dynamic which would be based on some data stored in the local storage as key value pair. To open a new tab from a safari extension i can do something similar to

```
var newTab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab();
newTab.url = safari.extension.baseURI + 'mainPage/mainPage.html';
```

where url will be a local html file. 
Now my **question** is how do i modify the local html file to insert dynamic content in it.

Comment: Your question is not well defined.

Comment: i have edited my question to be more precise

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. You have full control over mainPage.html, don't you? So you can include in it a script that will retrieve data from localStorage and modify the page based on that data in any way you want. You don't need to "modify the local html file", and in fact it's not possible to do so. Just use standard DOM manipulation techniques to add/change content in the document once it's been loaded.